# Cannot get React Router to load component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Am trying to use React Router 4.0 for some basic routing but cannot get it to load a different component.

When I run the app with a url of localhost/messages/ it loads the Folders component indicated by path='/', but when I change the URL to localhost/messages/mess I get a  404.

I don't seem to have any props available in my component.

My code is as follows

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Folders from "./components/msg_folders";
import Messages from "./components/messages";

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';



class Msgs extends Component  {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

render () {
return (

<Router> 
    <div id ='panelmessage'>
        <Route path="/mess/" component={Messages} />
        <Route path="/" component={Folders} />
    </div>

</Router>
      )  
}
}



ReactDOM.render(
<Msgs />
, document.querySelector('#panelcontainer'));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React router v4 nested route relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47205721/react-router-v4-nested-route-relative-path)

Comment: react-router v4 routes are absolute.  either build an absolute path, or use `match.url` from the parent route.

Comment: I've already tried absolute paths with no success.  When I try to use the match object I get 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined'. If I console.log this.props in the Msgs component, I get undefined.

Comment: Use`switch` to hold both `routes`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why do you add `message` (`localhost/message/mess` or `localhost/message`) to your url, bc you dont have a route that handle this path. You routes look good but you target it in a wrong way.
So to target you `Messages` component you should go to url > `localhost/mess` but not to `localhost/message/mess`. Seems like you add `message` into your `url` all the time, you can add a `basename` for your [`BrowserRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) as `/message`. Then you will be able to target it as you do.

Here is a [`worked example`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ppdqry?editors=0010) with similar setup as you have, so you can play with it.

```
const Message = (props) => (
  <div>
    Message props: {JSON.stringify(props.match.url)} <br/>
    <Link to='/'>Back to Home</Link>
  </div>
)

const App = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/mess' component={Message}/>
    <Route path='/' component={Home}/>
  </Switch>
)
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

My urls have `message` in them because I'm running the app from the /messages subdirectory.

I want `localhost/messages` to show the Folders component (which it does). I want `locahost/messages/mess` to show the Messages component (gives a 404).

Adding `basename='/message'` makes no difference.  The thing that appears to me to point to a potential cause is that the Msg props contain nothing i.e. no `match` object or any other object. I don't know what could cause this.  I can add a prop to Msgs in the `ReactDom.render` call and it shows up but there is nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this to work was by using HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter as The Reason put in his codepen above.  This however puts hashes in all my urls e.g. `http://localhost/bc/messages/#/mess` - don't know how to get rid of this.

The routing seems so basic, I can't believe how much time was spent on trying to get it work, surely there is a way using BrowserRouter?

Here is the code that works (with hash in the url)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Folders from "./components/msg_folders";
import Messages from "./components/messages";

import {HashRouter, BrowserRouter, Route, Switch,  Link, browserHistory} from 'react-router-dom';



class Msgs extends Component  {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }



render () { 

return (

<HashRouter  history={browserHistory}> 
<div id ='panelmessage'>

    <Route path="/mess"  component={Messages} />
    <Route exact path="/" component={Folders} />

</div>
 </HashRouter>       

      )  
}
}



ReactDOM.render(
    <Msgs  />
, document.querySelector('#panelcontainer'));
```